# TCP packets received are "scrambled"

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

As in these images (taken while browsing eBay, but happened in other sites too):

[image]
[image]

Sometimes the packets get "scrambled," and I have no idea why.

- Antivirus softwares don't seem to be the problem, since this happened no matter which AV I installed - Kaspersky, Avast, or Webroot.
- It happened in Windows 7, 8, and it's still happening in Windows 10.
- It happened no matter which browser I use - IE, FF, or Chrome.
- I don't use Linux much, but it never happened (yet) when I was using Arch Linux.
- I use Intel 6230 and 7260 WLANs together, but I rarely connect both at once. It happens no matter which one is the connected one.
- Nothing is logged in Event Viewer.
- ISP doesn't seem to be the problem here, since this happened at least on 5 different ISPs.
- It seems to be happening more often when the latency to the host is low. When it's <5ms, it often continuously happens even when I refresh.
- It always happen randomly - it's not like I can reproduce this whenever I can.
- Chrome sometimes complains that the connection to the page is reset when it's on HTTPS; must be the fault of this.

What could be the reason here, and will I be able to fix this? Since the packet should have passed verification steps in TCP in order to be displayed in the browser, I think it's because of faulty driver, but I'm using newest Intel drivers with default settings, so I don't know if I can fix this myself.

Comment: Have you ever seen the problem happen on a different Wi-Fi network? For this corruption to get past both TCP checksums and 802.11 FCSs & ICVs suggests it's happening at your NAT gateway or proxy. Maybe it could be your Wi-Fi card, but only if it's doing TCP LRO.

Comment: @Spiff I did; it happened on Cisco devices, devices with Realtek, Ralink, or Broadcom chips, and so on. About LRO - I'm not sure what it exactly is, but for i7260, "ARP/NS offload over WoWLAN", "Packet Coalescing" is enabled and for i6230, no such option is available.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've ruled out many possible causes.

If you suspect the driver/card, which seems reasonable, I'd suggest getting a [cheap USB wireless card](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=usb+wireless+network+adapter) for further testing.

If the card/driver is the root cause then you can continue using the cheap card, or invest in a better internal card, depending on your needs.

If it doesn't fix the issue, well, you only spent $10 and you'll probably find a use for the USB card one day.

Comment: Oh, right, I remembered that I bought one before and I lost it... All the WLAN adapters were reset and they'd keep doing so when I try to connect at least one of them when I plugged in the USB. Anyway, I do think I never experienced this "scrambling" when I was using internal Realtek wired adapter, so it must be it.

Comment: Anyway, I'd like to know if someone has ever experienced the same problem before spending money on this!